# How to populate user GET variables using cookies or user meta table in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I’m running the latest versions of WordPress and ENFOLD on my site. The site is a marketing tool to sell a product.

Multiple people will use the site to promote to their teams, so I want to give them a URL that will pass in 3 GET variables. Or, some good way to pass in the variables.

`[domain.name]?usr=falcon&phn=800-900-7777&eml=[emailaddress]`

If the user does not pass any GET variables then a set of default variables must be used.

There are links on images, buttons and contact information on the site, that would need to populate with the users GET data, so the correct registration links, etc are generated.

What’s a simple way to do this? Is it to use `cookies`, or `user_meta` table, or use a multisite installation?

I want the GET `/meta_table` data to be available throughout the site once it is loaded in the URL on the home page. This is problematic because php starts fresh on page reload. I could also set up the users manually in the back end I suppose, but if this blows up that will take more admin time.

Please help me wrap my head around this problem and to understand the best solution considering the constraints of PHP.

I decided to go the cookie route with this and I wrote the following code (see attachment for code), and placed it in `functions.php`. The code:

1. uses `if(isset($_GET[‘user’]))` to look for three GET variables that were passed in the URL, like so:
   `[domainname]?usr=falcon&phn=720-745-1760&amp;eml=[email]`
2. If the GET variable `isset`, then the those values are set as a cookie with `setcookie`.
3. Else if the GET variables are empty the it sets cookies using default values.
4. lastly it creates a short code to place in Wordpress.

Everything works, but the problem is the function runs on every page and if the values are NOT again passed on that page the default values get placed.
What I want is to set the variables one time and carry them through the website as the user navigates. Even better, have the same variables in place the next time the user visits. I understand that PHP wipes everything and starts fresh every time a page is loaded.

What logic could I add to accomplish this?

May be what I am trying to do is more suited for placing the values in the user meta table in the database.

Looking for the best, reliable solution. Don't have to use cookies.